# How to get response header in angular using http interceptor

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

How to read the response headers in implementation of httpinteceptor in angular. I have exposed all the token in my node application. Since i am not able to read all the keys which is passed in response headers

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
      return next
        .handle(
          req.clone({
            headers: req.headers.append('API-Token', 'token')
          })
        )
        .pipe(
          tap((res: HttpEvent<HttpEventType>)  => {
            if (res instanceof HttpResponse) {
              console.log(res)
            }

          }),
          catchError({
            throw err;
          })
        );
    }
....
```

I had set the API token in backend Restify

```
this.restify.use((req, res, next) => {
                      res.header("api-token", 'GHYTYEUJSJSHHEYHJSH');
                      res.header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers","*");
                     next();
})
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you are not setting the headers in `Options` part instead you are appending them to the `body` that's why :p so just change this line

```
headers: req.headers.append('API-Token', 'token')
```

With this :

```
request.clone({  setHeaders: {  'API-Token': 'token'  }   });
```

After this you can findem in the `headers` object of the `HttpResponse`

```
  intercept( request: HttpRequest<any>,next: HttpHandler ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

                return next.handle(req).pipe(
                    tap(res=> {
                        if (res instanceof HttpResponse) {
                               console.log( res.headers.get('API-Token'));                                   
                        }
                    }),
                    catchError((err: any) => {
                           console.log(err)
                        return of(err);
                    }));

              }

        }
```

Inside your `node server`, you have missed a `return` statement in your code :

```
this.restify.use((req, res, next) => {
                      res.header("API-TOKEN", 'GHYTYEUJSJSHHEYHJSH');
                     return next();
})
```

Comment: Its not there. Even when I checked res.headers.headers,some default headers only shown.Not the actual headers

Comment: If it's still not working, make sure that you added you interceptor into providers of your module as follow { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: YourXhrInterceptor, multi: true }

Comment: I already added the above and still its not working.Edited the question and added the code part of restify.use where I had set the header.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subject, of } from 'rxjs';
import { MessageService } from './message/message.service';
import { LogService } from './log/log.service';
import { TokenService } from './auth/token.service';
import { UtilsService } from './utils/utils.service';

import { HttpClient, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest, HttpEvent, HttpResponse, HttpErrorResponse, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

export interface IValidationErrorInfo {
    message: string;
    members: string[];
}

export interface IErrorInfo {
    code: number;
    message: string;
    details: string;
    validationErrors: IValidationErrorInfo[];
}

export interface IAjaxResponse {
    success: boolean;
    result?: any;
    targetUrl?: string;
    error?: IErrorInfo;
    unAuthorizedRequest: boolean;
    __app: boolean;
}

@Injectable()
export class appHttpConfiguration {

    constructor(
        private _messageService: MessageService,
        private _logService: LogService) {
    }

    defaultError = <IErrorInfo>{
        message: 'An error has occurred!',
        details: 'Error details were not sent by server.'
    };

    defaultError401 = <IErrorInfo>{
        message: 'You are not authenticated!',
        details: 'You should be authenticated (sign in) in order to perform this operation.'
    };

    defaultError403 = <IErrorInfo>{
        message: 'You are not authorized!',
        details: 'You are not allowed to perform this operation.'
    };

    defaultError404 = <IErrorInfo>{
        message: 'Resource not found!',
        details: 'The resource requested could not be found on the server.'
    };

    logError(error: IErrorInfo): void {
        this._logService.error(error);
    }

    showError(error: IErrorInfo): any {
        if (error.details) {
            return this._messageService.error(error.details, error.message || this.defaultError.message);
        } else {
            return this._messageService.error(error.message || this.defaultError.message);
        }
    }

    handleTargetUrl(targetUrl: string): void {
        if (!targetUrl) {
            location.href = '/';
        } else {
            location.href = targetUrl;
        }
    }

    handleUnAuthorizedRequest(messagePromise: any, targetUrl?: string) {
        const self = this;

        if (messagePromise) {
            messagePromise.done(() => {
                this.handleTargetUrl(targetUrl || '/');
            });
        } else {
            self.handleTargetUrl(targetUrl || '/');
        }
    }

    handleNonappErrorResponse(response: HttpResponse<any>) {
        const self = this;

        switch (response.status) {
            case 401:
                self.handleUnAuthorizedRequest(
                    self.showError(self.defaultError401),
                    '/'
                );
                break;
            case 403:
                self.showError(self.defaultError403);
                break;
            case 404:
                self.showError(self.defaultError404);
                break;
            default:
                self.showError(self.defaultError);
                break;
        }
    }

    handleappResponse(response: HttpResponse<any>, ajaxResponse: IAjaxResponse): HttpResponse<any> {
        var newResponse: HttpResponse<any>;

        if (ajaxResponse.success) {
            newResponse = response.clone({
                body: ajaxResponse.result
            });

            if (ajaxResponse.targetUrl) {
                this.handleTargetUrl(ajaxResponse.targetUrl);;
            }
        } else {
            newResponse = response.clone({
                body: ajaxResponse.result
            });

            if (!ajaxResponse.error) {
                ajaxResponse.error = this.defaultError;
            }

            this.logError(ajaxResponse.error);
            this.showError(ajaxResponse.error);

            if (response.status === 401) {
                this.handleUnAuthorizedRequest(null, ajaxResponse.targetUrl);
            }
        }

        return newResponse;
    }

    getappAjaxResponseOrNull(response: HttpResponse<any>): IAjaxResponse | null {
        if(!response || !response.headers) {
            return null;
        }

        var contentType = response.headers.get('Content-Type');
        if (!contentType) {
            this._logService.warn('Content-Type is not sent!');
            return null;
        }

        if (contentType.indexOf("application/json") < 0) {
            this._logService.warn('Content-Type is not application/json: ' + contentType);
            return null;
        }

        var responseObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response.body));
        if (!responseObj.__app) {
            return null;
        }

        return responseObj as IAjaxResponse;
    }

    handleResponse(response: HttpResponse<any>): HttpResponse<any> {
        var ajaxResponse = this.getappAjaxResponseOrNull(response);
        if (ajaxResponse == null) {
            return response;
        }

        return this.handleappResponse(response, ajaxResponse);
    }

    blobToText(blob: any): Observable<string> {
        return new Observable<string>((observer: any) => {
            if (!blob) {
                observer.next("");
                observer.complete();
            } else {
                let reader = new FileReader(); 
                reader.onload = function() { 
                    observer.next(this.result);
                    observer.complete();
                }
                reader.readAsText(blob); 
            }
        });
    }
}

@Injectable()
export class appHttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    protected configuration: appHttpConfiguration;
    private _tokenService: TokenService = new TokenService();
    private _utilsService: UtilsService = new UtilsService();
    private _logService: LogService = new LogService();

    constructor(configuration: appHttpConfiguration) {
        this.configuration = configuration;
    }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    var interceptObservable = new Subject<HttpEvent<any>>();
    var modifiedRequest = this.normalizeRequestHeaders(request);

    next.handle(modifiedRequest)
        .subscribe((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
            this.handleSuccessResponse(event, interceptObservable );
        }, (error: any) => {
            return this.handleErrorResponse(error, interceptObservable);
        });

    return interceptObservable;
  }

  protected normalizeRequestHeaders(request: HttpRequest<any>):HttpRequest<any> {
        var modifiedHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        modifiedHeaders = request.headers.set("Pragma","no-cache")
                                            .set("Cache-Control","no-cache")
                                            .set("Expires", "Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT");

        modifiedHeaders = this.addXRequestedWithHeader(modifiedHeaders);
        modifiedHeaders = this.addAuthorizationHeaders(modifiedHeaders);
        modifiedHeaders = this.addAspNetCoreCultureHeader(modifiedHeaders);
        modifiedHeaders = this.addAcceptLanguageHeader(modifiedHeaders);
        modifiedHeaders = this.addTenantIdHeader(modifiedHeaders);

        return request.clone({
            headers: modifiedHeaders
        });
    }

    protected addXRequestedWithHeader(headers:HttpHeaders):HttpHeaders {
        if (headers) {
            headers = headers.set('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
        }

        return headers;
    }

    protected addAspNetCoreCultureHeader(headers:HttpHeaders):HttpHeaders {
        let cookieLangValue = this._utilsService.getCookieValue("app.Localization.CultureName");
        if (cookieLangValue && headers && !headers.has('.AspNetCore.Culture')) {
            headers = headers.set('.AspNetCore.Culture', cookieLangValue);
        }

        return headers;
    }

    protected addAcceptLanguageHeader(headers:HttpHeaders):HttpHeaders {
        let cookieLangValue = this._utilsService.getCookieValue("app.Localization.CultureName");
        if (cookieLangValue && headers && !headers.has('Accept-Language')) {
            headers = headers.set('Accept-Language', cookieLangValue);
        }

        return headers;
    }

    protected addTenantIdHeader(headers:HttpHeaders):HttpHeaders {
        let cookieTenantIdValue = this._utilsService.getCookieValue('app.TenantId');
        if (cookieTenantIdValue && headers && !headers.has('app.TenantId')) {
            headers = headers.set('app.TenantId', cookieTenantIdValue);
        }

        return headers;
    }

    protected addAuthorizationHeaders(headers:HttpHeaders): HttpHeaders {
        let authorizationHeaders = headers ? headers.getAll('Authorization'): null;
        if (!authorizationHeaders) {
            authorizationHeaders = [];
        }

        if (!this.itemExists(authorizationHeaders, (item: string) => item.indexOf('Bearer ') == 0)) {
            let token = this._tokenService.getToken();
            if (headers && token) {
                headers = headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
            }
        }

        return headers;
    }

    protected handleSuccessResponse(event: HttpEvent<any>, interceptObservable: Subject<HttpEvent<any>>): void{
        var self = this;

        if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
            if (event.body instanceof Blob && event.body.type && event.body.type.indexOf("application/json") >= 0){
                var clonedResponse = event.clone();
        
                self.configuration.blobToText(event.body).subscribe(json => {
                    const responseBody = json == "null" ? {}: JSON.parse(json);
            
                    var modifiedResponse = self.configuration.handleResponse(event.clone({
                        body: responseBody
                    }));
            
                    interceptObservable.next(modifiedResponse.clone({
                        body: new Blob([JSON.stringify(modifiedResponse.body)], {type : 'application/json'})
                    }));

                    interceptObservable.complete();
                });
            } else {
                interceptObservable.next(event);
                interceptObservable.complete();
            }
        } else {
            interceptObservable.next(event);
        }
    }

    protected handleErrorResponse(error: any, interceptObservable: Subject<HttpEvent<any>>): Observable<any> {
        var errorObservable = new Subject<any>();

        if(!(error.error instanceof Blob)){
            interceptObservable.error(error);
            interceptObservable.complete();
            return of({});
        }

        this.configuration.blobToText(error.error).subscribe(json => {
            const errorBody = (json == "" || json == "null") ? {}: JSON.parse(json);
            const errorResponse = new HttpResponse({
                headers: error.headers,
                status: error.status,
                body: errorBody
            });

            var ajaxResponse = this.configuration.getappAjaxResponseOrNull(errorResponse);
    
            if (ajaxResponse != null) {
                this.configuration.handleappResponse(errorResponse, ajaxResponse);
            } else {
                this.configuration.handleNonappErrorResponse(errorResponse);
            }

            errorObservable.complete();
    
            interceptObservable.error(error);
            interceptObservable.complete();
        });

        return errorObservable;
    }

    private itemExists<T>(items: T[], predicate: (item: T) => boolean): boolean {
        for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            if (predicate(items[i])) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to cast headers to HttpHeaders like this

```
....
    if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
        let headers: HttpHeaders = event.headers
        console.log(headers.get('token')) 
    }
....
```